# Linear equation, incompatible types BOOLEAN/LONGINT

Tags: pascal, operator-precedence

I've got exercise about linear equation in Pascal and I've created simple code for comparison input numbers but when I try to run it. I have problem about incompatible types, `got BOOLEAN and expected LONGINT`.

```
program LinearEquation;

var
  a, b: real;

begin
  readln(a, b);

  if (b = 0 and a = 0) then
    writeln('INFINITY')
  else if (b = 0 and a <> 0) then
    writeln(1)
  else if (a = 0 and b <> 0) then
    writeln(0)
  else if(b mod a = 0) then
    writeln(1);

  readln;

end.
```

and

```
13 / 9 rownan~1.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "BOOLEAN" expected "LONGINT"
15 / 14 rownan~1.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "BOOLEAN" expected "LONGINT"
17 / 14 rownan~1.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "BOOLEAN" expected "LONGINT"
17 / 14 rownan~1.pas
 Error: Incompatible types: got "BOOLEAN" expected "LONGINT"
```

Comment: Read up about the precedence of operators, or just add more (). The rules for operator precedence vary with languages. Note that the outer () in if statements are redundant in Pascal.

Comment: ...in other words, you want `if (b=0) and (a=0) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in [modern Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence), `and` has higher precedence than `=`, so

```
a = 0 and b = 0
```

is interpreted as

```
(a = (0 and b)) = 0.
```

But the `and` operator cannot accept an integer and a floating-point value as operands (two integers would have been OK, though). Hence the error.

Had `a` and `b` been integers, `0 and b` would have been the bitwise conjunction of `0` and `b`, that is, `0`. Thus, we would have had

```
(a = 0) = 0.
```

This reads either `true = 0` (if `a` is equal to `0`) or `false = 0` (if `a` is different from `0`). But a boolean cannot be compared to an integer, so the compiler would have complained about that.

Still, this was just an academic exercise. Clearly, your intension was

```
(a = 0) and (b = 0).
```

Just add the parentheses:

```
if (b = 0) and (a = 0) then
  writeln('INFINITY')
```